# Change onclick function when calling base on class

Tags: jquery, function, onclick

I have 6 buttons. First 3 belongs to f-click class, And all buttons belongs to s-click. Firstly I want to run functionOne by calling f-click. Then quickly should be disable to call again onclick f-click and want to be call onclick ussing s-click class.
My conditions are bellow As a example, If buttons are 1 2 3 4 5 6.

1. I want to get message as "your in.." by onclick 1,2 or 3.
2. 4,5,6 should not be call until message as "your in.."
3. if message "your in.." I want to be call button value like "your clik on"+button_value.(1 to 6)
4. should not be get  "your in.." message 2 times.

how to I can do that, and my code is as follow,

```html
<button type="button" id="b_1" value="0" class="f-click s-click btn" name="button"></button>
<button type="button" id="b_2" value="1" class="f-click s-click btn" name="button"></button>
<button type="button" id="b_3" value="2" class="f-click s-click btn" name="button"></button>
<button type="button" id="b_4" value="3" class="s-click btn" name="button"></button>
<button type="button" id="b_5" value="4" class="s-click btn" name="button"></button>
<button type="button" id="b_6" value="5" class="s-click btn" name="button"></button>
```

This is my jquery code,

```js
$(".f-click").on('click', function() {
 firstFunction()
 secondFunction();
});

function firstFunction() {
 $(".f-click").prop("disabled", true);
 console.log("Your In");
 }

function secondFunction() {
 $(".s-click").prop("disabled", false);
 var selected_button = $(this).val();

 $(".s-click").on('click', function() {
 console.log("Your click on : "+selected_button);
 });
}
```

But it not working, because second function work with again first function, What I want to do.

Comment: "_I have 6 buttons belongs to f-click class, And first 3 buttons belongs to s-click_" Wrong, you have 6 s-click and 3 f-click

Comment: Also, "_and want to be call base on s-click._" not sure what this means and what does "base" means here?

Comment: ok I will change it

Comment: @palaѕн I think, now can be understand. Isn`t it?

Comment: You have so many contradictory requirements. I think you are confused what you actually want. Firstly, you said "_how to block second function until call first function_".. then you are saying "_if I click on any buttons in 1 , 2, or 3, I want to disable that all 3 buttons, and then run second function_"

Comment: Also, think deeply about what your main requirements are, so that once you get a solution you should not have to say, this works, but how can I also do this.. ok your this solution also works, but how can I also do this.. Maybe break your question into multiple parts and create a separate question for each one of them so that you can focus on one issue at a time.

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: Please also update your code to match your new requirements as at #1 you said "_ant to get message as "your in.." by onclick 1,2 or 3._" but in your code you have "console.log("this is 1st function");". Also, update your code for "I want to be call button value like "your clik on"+button_value._" as no where I can see the same console log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213314/discussion-between-lakmal-bodhinayaka-and-pala).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few issues here:

1. Inside `firstFunction()` you are calling `$(".f-click").prop("disabled", true);` but again inside `secondFunction()` you are calling `$(".s-click").prop("disabled", false);` and as all 6 buttons have this class thus `.f-click` buttons are never disabled.
2. You can fix this by not including `.f-click` buttons on `.s-click` disable like:

   ```
   $(".s-click:not(.f-click)").prop("disabled", false);
   ```
3. Also, inside `secondFunction()` you are assigning the `click` event handler to `.s-click` buttons multiple times. Thus on first click it shows 1 console log, then 2 and so on. To resolve this you should put the `click` event handler for `.s-click` buttons outside the `secondFunction()` and just trigger the click like:

   ```
   $(".s-click").click();
   ```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.f-click', function() {
  firstFunction(this)
});

$(document).on('click', '.s-click:not(.f-click)', function() {
  secondFunction();
});

function firstFunction(obj) {
  $(obj).removeClass('f-click')
  console.log("this is 1st function");
}

function secondFunction() {
  console.log("this is 2nd function");
}
```

```css
.btn { padding: 4px 15px;  margin: 4px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="b_1" value="0" class="f-click s-click btn" name="button">1</button>
<button type="button" id="b_2" value="1" class="f-click s-click btn" name="button">2</button>
<button type="button" id="b_3" value="2" class="f-click s-click btn" name="button">3</button>
<button type="button" id="b_4" value="3" class="s-click btn" name="button">4</button>
<button type="button" id="b_5" value="4" class="s-click btn" name="button">5</button>
<button type="button" id="b_6" value="5" class="s-click btn" name="button">6</button>
```

Comment: but I want to call all (6) buttons to run second function what I do for that?

Comment: please tell me, how to block second function until call first function. and first time when click 1,2 or 3 should be run only 1st function

Comment: Brother, it works fine, but I have some situation, if I click on any buttons in 1 , 2, or 3, I want to disable that all 3 buttons, and then run second function. but until click first 3 should cant be call second function. it means 4,5 ,6 disabled until click 1,2 or 3

Comment: I am not getting what you mean here. Please update your main post with details and examples.

Comment: I have some changes but this enough as my quection

Answer (score 0):

move this:

```
$(".s-click").on('click', function() {
 console.log("this is 2nd function");
 });
```

outside of

```
function secondFunction() {
```

then call .off() before .on for every click event handler

```
$(".f-click").off().on('click', function
```

... and for your other click handler as well

Comment: can be disable run second function until clik first 3.?